# getElementByTagName() not working?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-table

1. In my page I've got 3 table elements, I want to access the 3rd  element using its tagname.

   So, I used `document.getElementByTagName("table")[2];`
2. Later, I tried to obtain value of an element in that table by      `table.children[0].children[1].children[2].innerHTML;`
3. Then, I tried to modify the already existing `<p>`element with   `id="ID"` .

   But I'm not getting the value modified?

**Whats wrong with my script?**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
  <body>
    ID  : <p id="ID"></p>
 <body>
<table>
  
</table>
<table>
  
</table>

<table>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
  
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Class</td>
    <td>25</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script>

var table = document.getElementByTagName("table")[2];
 var id = table.children[0].children[1].children[2].innerHTML;
 
document.getElementById("ID").innerHTML = id;
    
    </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's `getElementsByTagName`, plural.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As with most DOM methods that return a Node list, the name is *plural* - `getElementsByTagName`.

Answer (score 3):

It is `document.getElementsByTagName` - plural form!

Because it has the possibility to return multiple elements in a NodeList - hence Element`s`.

Answer (score 2):

document.getElementsByTagName "PLURAL"

Answer (score 2):

use

`document.getElementsByTagName("table")[2];` instead of `document.getElementByTagName("table")[2];`